# Archlinux: modprobe: invalid option -- 'l'

Tags: arch-linux

Just synchronized and updated all packages on my Arch Linux.

Now I try to find out all available modules by `modprobe -l`

But I got:  `modprobe: invalid option -- 'l'`

/sbin/modprobe was linked from /usr/bin/kmod , which exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like `modeprobe -l` has gone the way of the dinosaurs.  If you look in the Arch Linux wiki, you can find [this replacement](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=134393).  As I see it, this is the interesting line:

```
   find /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/ -iname "*$1*.ko*" | cut -d/ -f5-
```

That line works for me on an Arch linux just synced and updated this morning.  The shell that ran it had no value for $1, so that pipeline ended up as this:

```
   find /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/ -iname "**.ko*" | cut -d/ -f5-
```

Dadgum, there's a lot of modules.

Comment: Nope. It is basically not the same as the find-command leaves out the modules within the extra-modules directory that modprobe basically knows. But as the extra-modules directory does not contain the revision version of the kernel you cannot even trust uname to find the proper directory name. So the above command does not list the virtualbox-modules (for example).